# Proper way to work with a hash in RUBY

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash of a menu that I need to iterate over values. Each item has two sizes `SML` and `LRG`. Let's assume this is my `hash`.

```
fullMenu = [{:item => "pasta",   :sml => 550, :lrg => 975}, 
            {:item => "chicken", :sml => 725, :lrg => 1150},
            {:item => "shrimp",  :sml => 975, :lrg => 1350}]
```

Now what I would like to do is iterate over each `item / size - price` to build out the menu.

```
fullMenu.each do |item, p_sml, p_lrg|
    puts "#{item} Small: $#{p_sml} -or- Large: $#{p_lrg}"
end
```

My output is:

```
{:item=>"pasta", :sml=>550, :lrg=>975} Small: $ -or- Large: $
{:item=>"chicken", :sml=>725, :lrg=>1150} Small: $ -or- Large: $
{:item=>"shrimp", :sml=>975, :lrg=>1350} Small: $ -or- Large: $
```

Not exactly what I want. As nothing is being output. Lastly I actually want my `puts` to be `puts "#{item} Small: $#{"%.2f" % p_sml / 100} -or- Large: $#{"%.2f" % p_lrg / 100}"` To properly display price. What am I missing here? And is this called a multidimensional `hash` or `array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fullMenu = [{:item => "pasta",   :sml => 550, :lrg => 975}, 
            {:item => "chicken", :sml => 725, :lrg => 1150},
            {:item => "shrimp",  :sml => 975, :lrg => 1350}]

fullMenu.each { |h|
  puts "%s Small: %.2f -or- Large: %.2f" % [h[:item], h[:sml]/100.0, h[:lrg]/100.0]
}
```

output:

```
pasta Small: 5.50 -or- Large: 9.75
chicken Small: 7.25 -or- Large: 11.50
shrimp Small: 9.75 -or- Large: 13.50
```

Comment: Yep! Thank you. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `map` on the values of the hashes:

```
2.0.0p247 :010 > fullMenu = [{:item => "pasta",   :sml => 550, :lrg => 975}, 
2.0.0p247 :011 >                 {:item => "chicken", :sml => 725, :lrg => 1150},
2.0.0p247 :012 >                 {:item => "shrimp",  :sml => 975, :lrg => 1350}]
 => [{:item=>"pasta", :sml=>550, :lrg=>975}, {:item=>"chicken", :sml=>725, :lrg=>1150}, {:item=>"shrimp", :sml=>975, :lrg=>1350}] 
2.0.0p247 :013 > fullMenu.map(&:value)
 => [{:item=>"pasta", :sml=>550, :lrg=>975}, {:item=>"chicken", :sml=>725, :lrg=>1150}, {:item=>"shrimp", :sml=>975, :lrg=>1350}] 

2.0.0p247 :014 > fullMenu.map(&:values)
 => [["pasta", 550, 975], ["chicken", 725, 1150], ["shrimp", 975, 1350]]
```

Then, your code would work:

```
fullMenu.each do |item, p_sml, p_lrg|
  puts "#{item} Small: $#{p_sml} -or- Large: $#{p_lrg}"
end
```

*And is this called a multidimensional hash or array?*

This would be an array of hashes.  If you wanted, you could do an array of arrays, but I think this way works.

**EDIT** - All this said, the better way to do it is what @falsetru has.

Comment: "An array of hashes." Thanks CDub, is this an optimal way to use array/hashes or would you suggest a more efficient setup?

Comment: I'd totally use @falsetru's answer. :)

Comment: Thanks - I meant though do you think setting up my array/hash like I did is optimal?

Comment: Oh, I hear ya.  An array of hashes is fine, but I'd definitely read the hashes the way @falsetru does, since the order of key/value pairs in the hash isn't guaranteed.